# display: inline-block not working Outlook Email HTML

Tags: python, html, css, html-email

I want to set one table and one image in same line of email.
`display: inline;` is working fine in any browser but in outlook email everything is in one column, I need them to in same line. Please help me with solution.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    img {
      display: inline;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body> <img src="Image1.jpg">
  <h1>afdsgdf dfgsdf dsfgf</h1> <img src="Image2.jpg">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: display: inline-block is supported by Outlook. Try adding it as an inline style.

Answer (score 1):

Coding HTML for Email clients is completely different to coding for web browsers. And on top of that every email client will render your code differently. It is a far too extensive topic to go into here so I would advise doing some research online. However, to get you started, the most reliable way to write HTML for email is to use a table layout with HTML table tr td tags etc.

Also many email clients ignore style tags so you may want to write your CSS inline like this -

```
 <img style="display: inline; width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="img1.jpg" /> 
 <h1 style="display:inline"> Im a header </h1>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not working for my outlook email. Please suggest any other way to do it.